# Updating IBM Websphere 8.5.5.14 and Java 1.7 on windows 2008 Server

Tags: installation, websphere

I have a task to update 8.5.5.2 web sphere to 8.5.5.14 on a windows 2008 server. I have java 1.7 already installed (and java 6 as well) and all the profiles uses it.

How ever when i try to apply fix patch using IBM installation manager, by default it's installing Java 8 which is not supported on windows 2008.

Is there a way where i can by pass java 8 and install only the fix patch (8.5.5.14) from installation manager.

Any pointer/help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Installation Manager Screenshot:
[image: Installation Manager Screen Shot]

Answer (score 1):

No, WebSphere 8.5.5.14 requires Java 8, and Java 8 is not supported on Windows 2008 Server.  If you must stay with Windows 2008 you can't update WebSphere past 8.5.5.13. More detail here:  [IBM WebSphere SDK Java Technology Edition 8.0 Minimum Supported Operating Systems](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27045339)

Comment: Thanks @Evan. I am sure that 8.5.5.14 supports Java 1.7 at least until Sep 2019.Is there a way if i can still upgrade to 8.5.5.14 and Java 1.7. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what IBM documentation ( https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27045339 ) says, I did some shortcuts to make key points easier to notice in a long article:

```
In 8.5.5.14 and later, it is planned that (Java8) SDK will be required for all new installations and all updates (fixpacks).

In 8.5.5.14 (...) prior operating system releases (such as Windows 2008 (...) ) will no longer be supported.
```

So unfortunately what you are trying to do is not supported:

Although Java7 is still fine as a runtime environment for your servers, for example if your business application is not yet Java8 compatible, you need to have Java8 installed as a default JVM for Websphere 8.5.5.14 "internal" requirements.

You cant have IBM's Java8 installed in Windows2008, which is mandatory for Websphere 8.5.5.14, that means you cant install Websphere 8.5.5.14.

In the end, I would like to remind you, that you can upgrade to a previous release: 8.5.5.13. Version 8.5.5.13 is 11 fixpacks newer than what you already have, maybe it will suffice for your needs.

Comment: Thanks. I had applied patch 8.5.5.13 with Java 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line - upgrade windows to a current version that's not 11 years old. Or, better yet, put it on Linux. WAS is great on Linux! Red Hat, Suse, OpenSuse, Fedora, CentOS are good flavors.

Comment: Thanks Kenny. Greatly appreciate your suggestion.